# How to refer to members of the House of Representatives?

Tags: writing-style, word-choice

The sentence is

> Call your two Senators and your elected member of the House of Representatives.

I'd like to say something simpler like *… your elected Congressman*, but that runs into all sorts of issues. First, we can have either a *congressman* or a *congresswoman*. Second, Senators *are* "congressmen." So how to refer to people of the other house?

Comment: "Your elected representatives" or "your members of Congress." But asking for rephrasings of single sentences and phrases is off-topic here.

Comment: You can also lump them together as "Congressional delegates".

Comment: This looks like it's more of a word ID question. I'll see if English will take it.

Comment: I can give you several gender-neutral options; unfortunately, none of them are suitable for use in polite company.

Answer (score 3):

The term **[Representative](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/Representative)** (with a capital *R*) means

> a politician who is a member of the U.S. House of Representatives

Especially when used in the context of a sentences that references *Senators and Representative*, there is little likelihood of confusion.

Comment: As it says on the House page "[Find Your Representative](http://www.house.gov/#feature1)" !

Comment: @MarioElocio We were obviously on the same wave length typing at the same time. Thanks